# count the frequences of several variables for a given category

Tags: r

I have a table, that has the following format

```
time    ID
 1     4024
 1     4024
 1     4025
 1     4016
 2     4024
 2     4025
 2     4025
 3     4024
 3     4016
 3     4016
```

I want to count the frequence for each ID in each time point. For instance, I would like to generate the following table based on the above table

```
time  4024   4025 4016
1      2      1    1
2      1      2    0
3      1      0    2
```

It seems that `aggregate` function can help, but how to use it for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `table`

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1))
#  4016 4024 4025
#1    1    2    1
#2    0    1    2
#3    2    1    0
```

---

Or use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), time ~ID, length)
#     time 4016 4024 4025
#1:    1    1    2    1
#2:    2    0    1    2
#3:    3    2    1    0
```

---

Or with `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(time, ID) %>%
   summarise(Count = n()) %>%
   spread(ID, Count, fill = 0)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works. By the way, are there any difference between as.data.frame and as.data.frame.matrix?

Comment: @use288609 If you use `as.data.frame` it will convert to `long` format.  So, first the `table` is converted to `matrix` and then to `data.frame`.  it is like `as.data.frame(as.matrix(table(df1)))`